# How can I add values on a MySQL table that has 'id' as its column name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modifying Database IDs from Rails Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437753/modifying-database-ids-from-rails-console)

I am trying to write an API that would interact with the MySQL Tables of the Asterisk Server. I need to insert values on some pre-existing tables as part of the Registration API. However, I discovered that RoR won't let you have access on a Table column named 'id'. Is there a workaround for this?

```
  @sip = Sip.new({:id => "1234", :keyword => "key", :data => "data", :flags => "flag")
  @sip.save
```

Each time I try to run this code, the columns keyword, data and flags got the values except for the 'id' column. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This question has been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437753/modifying-database-ids-from-rails-console